# How to pass two lists from different functions into save() function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two functions that create X number of entry widgets based on the number a user inputted:

```
 def Pap_geo():
        num_Pap = int(Pap.get())
        Pap_GEOs = []
        for i in range(num_Pap):
            gt_geo = Entry(top, width=20)
            gt_geo.focus_set()
            gt_geo.grid(row=2+i, column=0, padx=20, pady=0, sticky="W")
            Pap_GEOs.append(gt_geo)
        return Pap_GEOs
```

and:

```
        def Sap_geo():
        num_Sap = int(Sap.get())
        Sap_GEOs = []
        for i in range(num_Sap):
            Sap_geo = Entry(top, width=20)
            Sap_geo.focus_set()
            Sap_geo.grid(row=2 + i, column=1, padx=20, pady=0, sticky="W")
            Sap_GEOs.append(Sap_geo)
        return Sap_GEOs
```

I want to be able to click 'ok' and print the results of these two lists. I've gotten as far as:

```
        def save():
        Pap_GEOs2 = []
        for j in Pap_geo():
            Pap_GEOs2.append(j.get())
        print(Pap_GEOs2)

        Sap_GEOs2 = []
        for j in Sap_geo():
            Sap_GEOs2.append(j.get())
        print(Sap_GEOs2)

    button = Button(top, text="Save", command=save)
    button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(170, 0), pady=(0, 10), sticky="W")
```

This prints two lists of the correct length, however they are empty. I had a similar question before, which was resolved. The solution was to create a list of the entry widgets then call get() on each of those widgets in the OK function. I thought that's what I was doing here but I am getting the same issue. Any input would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You create those `Entry` widgets inside `save()` and then get their values just after they are created, so you get empty strings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was wondering if you could clarify: I thought those entry widgets were being created in the above two functions, which return lists of entry widgets. Then in the save() function, I meant to loop through those lists and call .get() on each of those entries. I suppose that's not what's happening in the ok() function here?

Comment: Since you have called `Pap_geo()` and `Sap_geo()` inside `save()` which means new set of `Entry` widgets will be created every time `save()` is called.  You need to called the two functions elsewhere outside `save()` and then loop through `Pap_GEOs` and `Sap_GEOs` (assume they are global variables) instead inside `save()`.